# Captureing Control key with mouse down in Flash builder.

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4, mouseevent, zooming

I'm using PanZoomComponent in my application. When a user holds down control key with mouse press, I want to show hand tool by making PanZoomComponent object's propery `childPreventsPan = false;`. In short at combination of control key and mouse press I want to show Hand tool if not cursor. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you have troubles to catch the ctrlKey or to set the hand cursor? What does event.ctrlKey return?

Answer (score 2):

Use [special flag `ctrlKey` of `flash.events.MouseEvent`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/MouseEvent.html#ctrlKey).

Comment: Please post the problem to Adobe Flash Player bug tracker! In my practice `ctrlKey` is always passed correctly with `MouseEvent`. So you've found very interesting bug! Lets Adobe fix it!

Comment: For what it's worth, the `ctrlKey` seems to be always false for `MOUSE_DOWN` (at least for me on Windows 8 in Flash Player 11.5) and most of the time `false` on `MOUSE_UP` as well.